# Can I start my new iOS app with version number 2.0?

Tags: ios

Can I start my version number 2.0 for a new iOS app?

Comment: I find you have explain your (good) question not properly. Now after edit it looks nice. Try to do it by yourself next time please!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can start with 2.0. However subsequent release should be higher than it.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your application with any valid version number. You need to just keep in mind to give same version number as in iTuneConnect and info.plist file of application...